# Is it possible to hide a border, preserving its width?

Tags: css

I would like to conditionally apply a border to a `<div>` to highlight it (the framework used is Vue3 and Quasar, if this matters). The border would be `3px` wide.

In case a `<div>` is not highlighted, I would like it to still have a `3px`, but invisible. The reason for that is that I do not want the `<div>` to "jump" when the border is visible or not (the border takes some space, and the `<div>` will rearrange when it is missing).

I thought that `border-style: hidden` would be a solution, but the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) state that

> (...) the computed value of the same side's `border-width` will be 0, even if the specified value is something else

**Is there a simple way to hide the border, keeping its width for the DOM computations?**

(I would like to use generic solutions before jumping into calculating the margin dynamically)

Comment: use `transparent` color for `border-color`??

Comment: use outline and not border

Comment: Also, in some cases, setting box-sizing: border-box could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can set your border for your class with `border: 3px solid transparent;`, then change the color of the hovered div either by `border: 3px solid #F54333;` or by `border-color: #F54333;`

You can see an example below:

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5%;
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 5%; 
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.card:hover {
  border-color: #F54333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    Div 2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    Div 3
  </div>
</div>
```